# What is the most natural way to save a graphic view of a map generated by an Overpass Turbo query?

Tags: overpass-turbo

As a preface, I'm not very familiar with Overpass Turbo, so I may be giving too little or too much info. Please ask for clarification as needed.

***Brief version of the question:***

Someone built a query that draws on a map, and I want to save that drawing for future reference. What would be the most convenient way to do that? I don't want to have to re-run the query as it is pretty slow. Can I get a hyperlink to this data, or should I export it in some form, that could either be imported back to the website, or to another graphical tool? (A screenshot is not detailed enough for this situation.)

***Here's more background if you're curious:***

The game Pokemon Go, developed by Niantic, heavily uses data from OSM to determine where certain things will happen in the game. One example is using areas with certain tags, such as parks, and making them a "nest" in the game, where a specific Pokemon will appear frequently.

Certain individuals have managed to determine the exact timestamps of the data that Niantic uses for certain things, as well as the tags that are used. One such individual built a couple queries and posted them on Reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/8ep2ps/updated_osm_query_for_nests/). It is a map drawn by [this query](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/ytm), over my hometown, that I want to refer to.

Comment: The server only caches the query for the users session - it will not store it anywhere. Your best bet is to download the region your interested in and load it into a database (like postgis).

Comment: On overpass-turbo.eu you can save your queries online or offline (save button) or export the result as GeoJSON, GPX, KML, OSM, etc. (export button). Probably exporting it would be your choice. Then do whatever you want with it, e.g. share it as vector map.